# jQuery keydown event is not functioning after a button element is replaced with an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question. I've been coding a jQuery event where the  `button` with an ID of **add** is ticked and is updated to an `input`

Here is the jQuery code

```
/* Change the Add button to an Input element*/
$("#add").click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' placeholder='Task'>");
    $("div.tasks>span").remove();
});

/* Adding a value to the list */
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var item = $(this).val();

        $(this).parent().prepend("<li>" + item + "</li>");
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<header class="content-header">
    <img src="img/icon.png" alt="icon" class="header-icon">
    <h1>Monday</h1>
    <img src="img/icon.png" alt="icon" class="header-icon flipped"> 
    <!-- <p>6 <span>Tasks</span></p>-->
</header>
<div class="tasks"> 
    <hr>
    <button id="add"></button>
    <span> Add task</span>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Whats supposed to happen here is once the Button has been **ticked** it will now turn to an `input` element.

And once the `input` element has been populated with data and `keycode==13` is pressed (Enter). The value placed on the `input` element will now be added to the DOM within a `li` element.

Comment: Here is a working solution for your problem

[https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/a27d3pq7/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/a27d3pq7/1/)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, thanks for the heads up about that post! I'll be sure to read the heck out of it.

@Nishant123, whoa! Thanks! That's exactly what I need. I see you've used the `on()` and the `bindevent()` commands, I'm still not quite familiar with those two. But for the `on()` I kind of need a description as to what happened there. Thanks for the reply buddy!